# Recreating the effect by using replace color in photoshop

Tags: photoshop, luminance

I adjusted my image by using photoshop's replace color tool and changing the hue, saturation, and lightness sliders. Unfortunately I forgot the individual settings for each and I need to recreate the effect. I tried eye balling it and can't seem to do it...

Original:

[image]

Adjusted:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better method;

Select -> colour range

then
edit -> fill -> colour